# R shiny replace empty plot with message

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have dashboard with line plots. When there are filters applied and data is empty we see the empty plot without any lines. Instead of the empty plot I want to display text message saying no data available.

I see solution for python but I could not find one for R ([link](https://community.plotly.com/t/replacing-an-empty-graph-with-a-message/31497)). How would I go about showing the text message when there is not data to plot?

[image]

```
plot_ly(
            data = temp,
            y = ~value,
            x = ~Year_month,
            color = ~line_name
        ) %>%
            add_lines() %>%
            layout(
                yaxis = list(
                    tickformat = "%",
                    title = ""
                ),
                xaxis = list(title = ""),
                legend = list(
                    orientation = "h", yanchor = "bottom", y = -1,
                    font = list(size = 10)
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use this

```
if (is.null(temp)) {
   df <- data.frame()
   p <- ggplot(df) + geom_point() + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 10) +
      annotate("text", x=3.9, y=5.0, size=40, col="red", label="(" ) +
      annotate("text", x=5, y=5.6, size=12, col="red", label="o  o" ) +
      annotate("text", x=6.1, y=5.0, size=40, col="red", label=")" ) +
      annotate("text", x=5, y=5.1, size=12, col="red", label="|" ) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = 4.7, xend = 5.3, y = 4.4, yend = 4.4), size=2, color="red") +
      annotate("text", x=5, y=3, size=8, col="red", label="No Data")
   
   ggplotly(p)
}else{  ### your plotly code below
   plot_ly(...)
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I have another issue with plotly. Do you have any idea on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68548305/r-plotly-disable-default-hovertext-and-only-display-customized-text