# R plotly disable default hovertext and only display customized text

Tags: r, graph, plotly, r-plotly

[image]

I am struggling to disable the default hovertext. I have added custom hovertext but the default is still showing besides the custom text. I have tried hoverinfo = 'none' and hoverinfo = ''. In the screenshot above the arrow points to the default hover text. Is there a way to disable that text?

Here is my code:

```
temp <- structure(list(therapy_class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("ALK Inhibitors", 
"Anti-VEGF-based therapies", "EGFR TKIs", "Non-Platinum-based", 
"PD-1/PD-L1-based therapies", "Platinum-based", "Single agent chemotherapies", 
"Other"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Year_month = c("Jul 2020", 
"Aug 2020", "Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020", "Jul 2020", 
"Aug 2020", "Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020", "Jul 2020", 
"Aug 2020", "Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020", "Jul 2020", 
"Aug 2020", "Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020", "Jul 2020", 
"Aug 2020", "Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020", "Jul 2020", 
"Aug 2020", "Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020", "Jul 2020", 
"Aug 2020", "Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020", "Jul 2020", 
"Aug 2020", "Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020"), 
    value = c(0.028735632183908, 0.0327510917030568, 0.0239130434782609, 
    0.0245901639344262, 0.0237580993520518, 0.027972027972028, 
    0.0804597701149425, 0.0698689956331878, 0.0478260869565217, 
    0.0491803278688525, 0.0626349892008639, 0.0559440559440559, 
    0.0977011494252874, 0.111353711790393, 0.1, 0.108606557377049, 
    0.08207343412527, 0.0839160839160839, 0.00766283524904215, 
    0.0109170305676856, 0.00434782608695652, 0.00614754098360656, 
    0.00647948164146868, 0.0116550116550117, 0.478927203065134, 
    0.475982532751092, 0.456521739130435, 0.456967213114754, 
    0.511879049676026, 0.484848484848485, 0.162835249042146, 
    0.170305676855895, 0.239130434782609, 0.227459016393443, 
    0.183585313174946, 0.179487179487179, 0.0804597701149425, 
    0.0698689956331878, 0.0630434782608696, 0.0676229508196721, 
    0.08207343412527, 0.0955710955710956, 0.0632183908045977, 
    0.0589519650655022, 0.0652173913043478, 0.0594262295081967, 
    0.0475161987041037, 0.0606060606060606), count = c(15L, 15L, 
    11L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 42L, 32L, 22L, 24L, 29L, 24L, 51L, 51L, 
    46L, 53L, 38L, 36L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 250L, 218L, 210L, 
    223L, 237L, 208L, 85L, 78L, 110L, 111L, 85L, 77L, 42L, 32L, 
    29L, 33L, 38L, 41L, 33L, 27L, 30L, 29L, 22L, 26L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

    plot_ly(
    data = temp,
    y = ~value,
    x = ~Year_month,
    color = ~therapy_class
) %>%
    add_lines(
              hovertemplate = paste(temp$therapy_class,
                                    "<br>Count:", temp$count,
                                    "<br>PCT:", sprintf("%1.2f%%", 100*temp$value))) %>%
    layout(
        yaxis = list(
            tickformat = "%",
            title = ""
        ),
        xaxis = list(title = ""),
        legend = list(
            orientation = "h", yanchor = "bottom", y = -0.5,
            font = list(size = 10)
        )
    )
```

Comment: @YBS The info I want to show is inside the green box, the 3 lines. Outside the box it again shows the therapy class. The screenshot has the arrow pointed to the line I don't want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot_ly(
    data = temp,
    y = ~value,
    x = ~Year_month,
    color = ~therapy_class,
    name = ""
)
```

Needed to pass name parameter as "". It was using the default and using that in hover info.

[image]